# unexpected '@' in program in test target

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xctest

I have string constant declared as below. This code compilers in normal app debug and release target. But in app's test target (Ctrl + U), I got error that unexpected '@' in program in test target. Using xcode 7.

Modules are enabled as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256709/xcode-unit-test-build-error-unexpected-in-program).

HeaderA.h

```
#define URL_A   "http://www.example.com/service"
```

HeaderB.h

```
#define URL_AC          @URL_A
```

Got error  here, unexpected '@' in program. Expanded from macro @URL_AC

Modules are enabled as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256709/xcode-unit-test-build-error-unexpected-in-program).

[image]

Used in an .m file as,

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL_AC];
```

Even declaration of

```
#define URL_AC      @"https://www.example.com/service?format=json"
```

got 'Use of undeclared identifier URL_AC' compiler error.

Comment: Please show how `URL_AC` is being used.

Comment: updated in the question.

Comment: So you've got two errors?

Comment: I have two different form of define. The first form with C string got @ error, the 2nd form directly @"" define I got the 2nd error. So I guess test target have kind of misunderstanding of string literal, perhaps!

Comment: You will need to use [stringification](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101841/options-on-a-mac-for-a-writable-compressed-file-system) in order to reference one macro within another.  The second error seems to indicate that `HeaderB.h` has not been imported.

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem. The 'define' have some #ifdef macros. And this is controller using preprocessor declaration in the build settings. In my test target it was not defined. When I defined it, compiler gets the 'define' and all errors gone.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The 'define' have some #ifdef macros. And this is controlled using `preprocessor declaration` in the `build settings`. In my test target it was not defined. When I defined it, compiler gets the 'define' and all errors gone.

```
#if defined(TEST0)
#define URL0    "http://www.example.com"

#elif defined(TEST1)
#define URL1    "http://www.example2.com"

#endif
```