# 'unexpected '@' in program' error while building tests

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xctest, uitest

In my project I'm using macro called keypath from ReactiveCocoa:

```
NSString *lowercaseStringPath = @keypath(NSString.new, lowercaseString);
// => @"lowercaseString"

 * @endcode
 *
 * ... the macro returns an \c NSString containing all but the first path
 * component or argument (e.g., @"lowercaseString.UTF8String", @"version").
 *
 * In addition to simply creating a key path, this macro ensures that the key
 * path is valid at compile-time (causing a syntax error if not), and supports
 * refactoring, such that changing the name of the property will also update any
 * uses of \@keypath.
 */
#define keypath(...) \
    metamacro_if_eq(1, metamacro_argcount(__VA_ARGS__))(keypath1(__VA_ARGS__))(keypath2(__VA_ARGS__))

#define keypath1(PATH) \
    (((void)(NO && ((void)PATH, NO)), strchr(# PATH, '.') + 1))

#define keypath2(OBJ, PATH) \
    (((void)(NO && ((void)OBJ.PATH, NO)), # PATH))
```

It works fine with the main target. But when I try to run tests it shows me this error:
[image]

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256221/unexpected-in-program-in-test-target)

Which is quite similar to the issue at my project. but still different and have no helpful answer.
Do anyone have ideas how to solve it? cos I'm really stuck here and don't know where to move.

Comment: Is `TokenModel` in the test target as well as your main target?

Comment: Yes, sure, I had included it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TokenModel` should not be compiled into your test target. The test target should contain only test code (and any libraries that requires).

Go to your test target settings. Under General in the Testing section, make sure you've specified "Host Application". You may also need to enable the "Allow testing Host Application APIs" checkbox.

Then remove production code from your test target.